# How to deploy Django-Oscar on Openshift

Tags: python, django, web, openshift

I'm new to Stakoverflow and putting my first question here,also struggling to deploy django-oscar demo from github.I've followed the instruction from the documentation(http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.1/internals/sandbox.html):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar.git
$ cd django-oscar
$ virtualenv oscar
$ source ./oscar/bin/activate
(oscar) $ make sandbox
(oscar) $ sites/sandbox/manage.py runserver
```

It's OK when I test on ubuntu with python2.7 and get to the home page.However I don't know how to deploy the project to Openshit.And almost no any reference I can search and take. Someone knows that,do me a favour and that will be very appreciated.Thanks.
PS:I'm able to deploy usual django apps on openshift.

Comment: The OpenShift [developer portal](https://developers.openshift.com/) seems rather thorough for start up instructions.  You may get more helpful comments and answers from the community if you're more specific about what errors you are encountering or where you're stuck in your deployment process.

Comment: It cannot help.Thanks for your suggestion all the same.I have a little big progress on the issue but not solve either.And I wanna raise a  new question for what I encountered.

Comment: Thank you. I finally succeeded in the installation via using source setup(python setup install) instead of using 'pip install django-oscar'.